# JQuery Disable all checkboxes when select all is checked

Tags: jquery

I want to click on Select All and it will disable/fadeout the rest of the options.
But if select all isn't checked, then do whatever the code states.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        var count_checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
        var disable_checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length >= 3;  

        if ($("input.category_all:checked").is(':checked')) {
           $("input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",disable_checkbox);
        }

        $("input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled",disable_checkbox);

        if(count_checkbox > 0){
            $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">'+count_checkbox+' Selected</div>');
        }else{
            $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">Select...</div>');
        }
    });   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k6R7g/2/

Comment: you want `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` for disabled/checked.

Comment: can you show me how? I tried that and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what was going wrong is the `disable_checkbox` boolean - it is only true if you check three or more items (try checking b, c and d and you'll see) but your "Select All" wasn't actually selecting all at that point.

Here is a more elegant solution based on your own

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        var count_checkbox_all = $("input[type=checkbox]").not(".category_all").length;
        var count_checkbox_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").not(".category_all").length;

        if ($(this).hasClass("category_all")) { 
            //if we clicked on "Select All"
            var is_checked = $(".category_all").is(":checked");
            //check/uncheck everything and disable/enable the rest of the tickboxes based on the state of this one
            $(".categories_list").prop("checked", is_checked).attr("disabled",  is_checked);
            
            //also update the count of checked items
            count_checkbox_checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").not(".category_all").length;
        }
        
        if (count_checkbox_checked == count_checkbox_all) { //if all have been checked
            //make sure they are disabled and that "Select All" is checked as well
            $(".categories_list").attr("disabled",  true);
            $(".category_all").prop("checked", true);
        }
        
        if(count_checkbox > 0){
            $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">'+count_checkbox+' Selected</div>');
        }else{
            $('#checkbox_counter').replaceWith('<div id="checkbox_counter">Select...</div>');
        }
    });   
});
```

You can see it in action here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6R7g/8/)

If you click on "Select all", then it checks all the boxes (because afterwards you'll count the checked ones) and then disables them. If you untick it, then it clears the check of the boxes and enables them. The count is performed afterwards and excludes the "Select All" checkbox, because you conceptually only have 4 options - it doesn't make much sense to count the fifth one

Based on the comment by @Tyblitz, now when you individually select all checkboxes, you would get the effect of clicking Select All